# Всплывающая подсказка на Javascript

Tags: javascript

Необходимо написать всплывающую подсказку для элементов. Подсказка появляется после клика на элементе
Исходные данные

- Основная HTML-разметка
- Базовая CSS-разметка

Базовая разметка элемента, который нуждается в подсказке:

```html
<a href="" class="has-tooltip" title="Что бы вы хотели?">Помогите пожалуйста</a>
```

Шаблон подсказки выглядит так:

```html
<div class="tooltip">Текст подсказки</div>
```

Данные для текста подсказки берутся из атрибута `title`

Подсказки активируются классом `tooltip_active`
Процесс реализации

Реализуйте появление подсказки на основе положения текста
Показывайте подсказку при клике на элемент.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Всплывающая подсказка</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="task.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="logo__container">
          <a href="https://netology.ru/" class="logo__link"></a>
        </div>
        <h1 class="header__title">
            Домашнее задание к занятию 2.3 «Изменение структуры HTML-документа». Всплывающая подсказка.
        </h1>
    </header>
    <a href="" class="has-tooltip" title="Что бы вы хотели?">Помогите пожалуйста</a>
    <!-- <div class="tooltip" style="left: 0; top: 0">
      Проверка!
    </div> -->

    <a href="" class="has-tooltip" title="Устройтесь на работу!">Нажми сюда и выиграй миллион!</a>

    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi facere dolor dicta accusamus corporis itaque quam deleniti, earum similique alias nostrum corrupti aspernatur, beatae, veniam vel quidem tenetur, odit reiciendis.</div>
    <div>Laboriosam aliquid neque in itaque at eaque, similique nisi consequatur voluptatem nam blanditiis eum ab, pariatur, harum molestias quas veniam. Aliquam maxime ipsa neque earum accusantium suscipit quasi. Harum, atque.</div>
    <div>Commodi fugiat vitae facere, provident voluptatem architecto reprehenderit. Nemo natus, qui quia animi voluptatibus. Cupiditate dolores, ducimus, nihil adipisci nemo dolorum aliquam eveniet obcaecati aperiam quis eum corporis velit! Esse.</div>
    <div>Earum deleniti laborum sunt ea, inventore voluptatum. Excepturi maiores laboriosam fugit, inventore hic quae ipsum, sequi ipsam expedita quisquam provident velit dolorum natus atque qui dignissimos numquam, quam, debitis! Error!</div>
    <div>Autem iure cum, accusantium soluta dolor beatae voluptas, ipsa ad quas dignissimos. Laboriosam laborum praesentium necessitatibus cumque tempore animi similique corporis quas, ipsam suscipit id possimus deserunt vitae incidunt eos.</div>
    <div>Autem, temporibus, nihil. Debitis quasi ex minus, delectus
        <a href="" class="has-tooltip" title="Это просто подсказка!">Для просмотра подсказки нажмите сюда</a>
         doloremque officiis sint facere, ducimus impedit! Sit, minima, et modi reiciendis sequi quo, voluptas dignissimos fugit veritatis quis nobis dolor saepe. Nobis!</div>
    <div>Itaque eum maxime tempora soluta, impedit placeat, dolores quod esse quibusdam saepe consequatur pariatur maiores? Ex minima delectus unde sit repudiandae quidem maxime non velit aliquam temporibus nulla, magnam, laboriosam!</div>
    <div>Eum maiores doloribus, unde vel, doloremque, perferendis amet perspiciatis et distinctio natus veniam tempora magni possimus. Eius repellat molestiae nihil deserunt accusantium provident soluta eligendi, sequi possimus suscipit, laudantium, rem!</div>
    <div>Odit voluptas quisquam minus id magni, temporibus cupiditate rem aspernatur nihil ipsam? Minima, tempora perspiciatis doloribus ut nulla. Magni tempore repellendus voluptatem nisi esse minima ipsam, saepe facere et qui?</div>
    <div>Esse molestiae dolore hic sunt asperiores vitae odio ab voluptatum provident corporis, voluptates ducimus reiciendis inventore, placeat quasi minima dicta nemo voluptas voluptate unde, culpa illum? Modi qui, officia nobis.</div>
    <div>Enim blanditiis nesciunt, repudiandae, ipsa accusantium  quos vitae magnam modi? Quia eaque natus officiis excepturi adipisci optio voluptate quis ut <a href="" class="has-tooltip" title="Не важный текст подсказки">Посмотреть</a> praesentium vero. Adipisci pariatur molestias harum ullam, incidunt blanditiis officia!</div>
    <div>Beatae aspernatur eveniet doloribus ullam magnam, reprehenderit odio eius, laboriosam voluptatum cupiditate voluptate officiis fuga neque, inventore magni, labore assumenda porro dolores quidem. Accusantium temporibus consectetur architecto ab, a suscipit?</div>
    <div>Sit dicta eos magni vel quae est debitis ipsam eligendi veniam totam et perspiciatis reprehenderit itaque excepturi omnis autem nihil explicabo sequi ut optio, officia voluptates sed? Ipsam, rerum maiores.</div>
    <div>Doloremque fugiat nemo ea, id praesentium illum ab soluta cumque labore nam. Itaque reprehenderit vitae aliquid debitis rerum temporibus cupiditate quos dignissimos! Praesentium molestias provident vero quia esse recusandae magni.</div>
    <div>Soluta, rem reprehenderit dignissimos excepturi aut alias natus dicta, cumque, sequi, perferendis facere! Neque debitis veritatis ratione in aut, consectetur incidunt sunt cupiditate exercitationem! Perferendis nemo molestias facilis perspiciatis voluptas.</div>
    <div>Totam dicta esse iure <a href="" class="has-tooltip" title="Подсказка открыта">Посмотреть подсказку</a> repudiandae asperiores culpa accusamus facilis magnam aut nemo earum quia provident necessitatibus, nihil amet, praesentium voluptatibus animi temporibus libero dolorem quis eveniet dolore debitis nisi. Suscipit.</div>
    <div>Dolores, inventore, minima. Aut assumenda laudantium praesentium, molestiae cumque incidunt animi necessitatibus ut laboriosam. Porro cupiditate laboriosam, eum dicta ut repudiandae aliquam explicabo soluta. Quidem molestiae numquam unde accusantium quasi!</div>
    <div>Eveniet iusto, placeat architecto enim fugiat obcaecati, ullam perferendis in culpa commodi, provident magnam similique natus nobis. Illum, dolores, voluptate placeat laboriosam soluta cupiditate possimus, ea aspernatur quis debitis sint.</div>
    <div>Eligendi reiciendis doloremque veritatis rerum corporis voluptatem est expedita porro fuga quae. Nam hic asperiores consequatur odit, ea, illo vitae quis non, aperiam tenetur architecto sint, nisi iure ipsum laudantium.</div>
    <div>Ad, repellendus doloremque. Debitis molestiae recusandae vero, quasi autem iusto mollitia deserunt odio delectus voluptatum dicta quae, tempora sint doloremque rem. Quod eum fugiat magni nostrum, dolore eligendi vel nisi.</div>

    <a href="" class="has-tooltip" title="Выхода нет, скоро рассвет">Конец страницы</a>

    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut aspernatur praesentium ipsum perferendis voluptas omnis ab quidem, corrupti corporis aperiam, architecto, doloremque sequi at nisi fugit quaerat molestiae quae consectetur!</div>
    <div>Modi ab asperiores est quae consectetur inventore perferendis! Voluptatibus cumque voluptate repellat, earum ad nulla et natus eligendi. Repellat ad iusto facilis dolorem recusandae, modi suscipit sapiente soluta nihil quam!</div>
    <script src="task.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


let toolLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.has-tooltip');


let tooltip = document.querySelector('.tooltip');


function handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let target = event.target;
    let title = target.getAttribute('title');
    tooltip.classList.add('tooltip_active');
    
tooltip.innerText = title;
tooltip.style.top = target.offsetTop + target.offsetHeight + 'px';
tooltip.style.left = target.offsetLeft + 'px';






}



for (let i = 0; i < toolLinks.length; i++) {
    toolLinks[i].addEventListener('click' , handleClick);
}
```

вот JS код , который пытался написать но не работает. Можете  подсказать где ошибка или предложить свое решение?

Comment: Что конкретно не работает? Если по коду, то не проще ли добавить один обработчик на контейнер и отслеживать имеет ли target события атрибут title? Также при вычислении позиции необходимо учитывать размер документа/экрана, т.к. иначе позиция может сместиться за видимые пределы.

Comment: tooltip.classList.add('tooltip_active');   вот эта команда не работает если посмотреть в инспекторе

Comment: Как не работает? Не добавляет класс? Выбрасывает исключение? Ничего не происходит?

Comment: все разобрался, нашел готовое решение

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
    <div class="has-tooltip">Помогите пожалуйста</div>
    <div class="tooltip">Текст подсказки</div>
```

CSS

```
 .has-tooltip {
            width: 200px;
            background-color: #eee;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 10px 0;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .tooltip {
            display: none;
            width: 200px;
            height: 150px;
            background-color: #eee;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .tooltip.active {
            display: block;
        }
```

JS

```
const hasTooltip = document.querySelector('.has-tooltip'),
            tooltip = document.querySelector('.tooltip')
        hasTooltip.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            tooltip.classList.toggle('active')
        })
```